# Taking every second character from strings and joining not having correct output

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing a coding challenge and am having trouble understanding where my code is going wrong.

This is the challenge:

> For building the encrypted string: Take every 2nd char from the
>   string, then the other chars, that are not every 2nd char, and concat
>   them as new String. Do this n times!

Example output:

> ```
> "This is a test!", 1 -> "hsi  etTi sats!"
> "This is a test!", 2 -> "hsi  etTi sats!" -> "s eT ashi tist!"
> ```

My initial iteration produces the correct output, however my second iteration with the same method does not.
Am I missing something?

Edit: Forgot to add my output:

> ```
> hsi  etTi sats!
> hsi  ets eT asTi sats!hi tist!
> ```

```
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "This is a test!";
            var n = 2;
            var everySecondLetter = "";
            var otherLetters = "";

            //var newString = "";
            //var duplicateString = "";

            var iterate = 1;
            do
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= text.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        everySecondLetter += text[i - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otherLetters += text[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                text = everySecondLetter + otherLetters;
                iterate++;
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            } while (iterate <= n);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to clear your `everySecondLetter` and `otherLetters` between iterations, otherwise you just keep adding to the end of the previous iteration's values.  So like this:

```
        do
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    everySecondLetter += text[i - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    otherLetters += text[i - 1];
                }
            }
            text = everySecondLetter + otherLetters;

            //*** Add these two lines:
            everySecondLetter = "";
            otherLetters = "";

            iterate++;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        } while (iterate <= n);
```

Comment: Not based on the sample output. They want to "encrypt" the new string, which is why `text = everySecondLetter + otherLetters;` is in there

Comment: I am a stone cold moron. How did I not see that lol. Thanks.
@JohnG No the aim is to iterate over the modified string on the second run